# How to use AsyncTask in a different process?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm using a Service in different process of my app using `android:process=":MyService"` and I recognized that my AsyncTasks in MyService class doesn't work and execute, so how can I sync my datas with my Server in MyService class?

I just want to update my Server from this class cause it's a ForegroundService that should be active most of the times. I believe that defining MyService class as a separate process helps my app's battery usage. I've already defined an inner class and used it inside MyService class but it doesn't work at all, I also tried to use another custom asyncTask class Object in MyService class but it doesn't work either

here's an example of my code in MyService class:

```
    static class UpdatePoint extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        String userId = user.get(SessionManager.getKeyId()).toString();
        String coin = strings[1];
        String step = strings[2];

        String log_lat = strings[3];
        String log_lng = strings[4];
        String log_zone = strings[5];
        String log_address = strings[6];
        //Log.d("updatePoint","coin:"+coin+", step:"+step);
        try {
            String update_point_url = "http://mohregroup.ir/db-mapapa/updatePoint.php";
            URL url = new URL(update_point_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(5*1000);

            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("userId", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(userId, "UTF-8")
                    + "&" + URLEncoder.encode("coin", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(coin, "UTF-8")
                    + "&" + URLEncoder.encode("step", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(step, "UTF-8")
                    + "&" + URLEncoder.encode("log_lat", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(log_lat, "UTF-8")
                    + "&" + URLEncoder.encode("log_lng", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(log_lng, "UTF-8")
                    + "&" + URLEncoder.encode("log_zone", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(log_zone, "UTF-8")
                    + "&" + URLEncoder.encode("log_address", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(log_address, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));

            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
            }
            //Log.d("updatePoints response:", response.toString().trim());
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            Timber.d("done Successfully!");

            return response.toString();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

and using it inside another method of MyService class :

```
if (getAddress() != null) {
            if (getAddress().getFeatureName() == null && 
getAddress().getAddressLine(0) != null) {
                new UpdatePoint().execute(String.valueOf(coins), 
String.valueOf(steps),
                        String.valueOf(originLocation.getLatitude()), 
String.valueOf(originLocation.getLongitude()),
                        getAddress().getFeatureName(), "not titled");
            } else if (getAddress().getFeatureName() != null && 
getAddress().getAddressLine(0) == null) {
                new UpdatePoint().execute(String.valueOf(coins), 
String.valueOf(steps),
                        String.valueOf(originLocation.getLatitude()), 
String.valueOf(originLocation.getLongitude()),
                    "not titled", getAddress().getAddressLine(0));
        } else {
            new UpdatePoint().execute(String.valueOf(coins), String.valueOf(steps),
                    String.valueOf(originLocation.getLatitude()), String.valueOf(originLocation.getLongitude()),
                    getAddress().getFeatureName(), getAddress().getAddressLine(0));
        }
    } else {
        new UpdatePoint().execute(String.valueOf(coins), String.valueOf(steps),
                String.valueOf(originLocation.getLatitude()), String.valueOf(originLocation.getLongitude()),
                "not titled", "not titled");
    }
```

So, any Ideas about

**how to use an asyncTask in a service with different process?**

or

**any other way in order to update the server from a service with different process?**

any helps would be appreciated a lot!

Thanks.

Comment: why don't you look at work manager if battery saving is needed. you can then schedule your sync jobs . you could use a foreground service and a normal handler thread or thread. i don't think you need a service in a different process

Comment: Just read and apply if you found it useful

https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter

Comment: @Raghunandan thank you so much I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @ChandrakantDvivedi Thanks a lot! I'll check it out asap.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be using timer and when timer is finished you can call asynctask and reset the timer again.

Comment: it could be, but I'm not sure it's suitable for my purposes. i need to sync my app to the server as soon as possible.